# Round the string

Tags: code-golf, counting

Some decimal numbers cannot be precisely represented as binary floats due to the internal representation of the binary floats. For example: rounding 14.225 to two decimal digits does not result in 14.23 as one might expect but in 14.22.

**Python**:

```
In: round(14.225, 2)
Out: 14.22
```

Assume, however, that we have a string representation of 14.225 as '14.225', we should be able to achieve our desired rounding '14.23' as a string representation.

This approach can be generalized to arbitrary precision.

## Possible Python 2/3 Solution

```python
import sys

def round_string(string, precision):
    assert(int(precision) >= 0)
    float(string)

    decimal_point = string.find('.')
    if decimal_point == -1:
        if precision == 0:
            return string
        return string + '.' + '0' * precision

    all_decimals = string[decimal_point+1:]
    nb_missing_decimals = precision - len(all_decimals)
    if nb_missing_decimals >= 0:
        if precision == 0:
            return string[:decimal_point]
        return string + '0' * nb_missing_decimals

    if int(all_decimals[precision]) < 5:
        if precision == 0:
            return string[:decimal_point]
        return string[:decimal_point+precision+1]

    sign = '-' if string[0] == '-' else '' 
    integer_part = abs(int(string[:decimal_point]))
    if precision == 0:
        return sign + str(integer_part + 1)
    decimals = str(int(all_decimals[:precision]) + 1)
    nb_missing_decimals = precision - len(decimals)
    if nb_missing_decimals >= 0:
        return sign + str(integer_part) + '.' + '0' * nb_missing_decimals + decimals
    return sign + str(integer_part + 1) + '.' + '0' * precision
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python2#tZTdaoMwFMfvfYpDb5LMVlTYjax9EZGQzigBjZLYwZ7eJWrjx@zoBsuFQs7H/3dOTtKLum1UB/pTe17OC1DNTeZUd0rIEo@/I7SKvwstGkkSD8xiWnPVYSE7PJvgcoaQDPaialg3RRNv2MqNW80q2jYmCs4wGoNCyByjAI1xotj6neEUjZqT3elZWzib7FK8uyk5pfZ2d8EHo2a/IYKXOdsIyaqKTgDaMaYrJD9KssFXXmkttDYOy5AZ7wQVl3iZ0dW4F3pZVfObQtNkBZg9LnwoeUfcu4PZA10Spw4iI/AGr/8JuPHyXXo/ykZALUqjBeiErPwUFWZW3u7xSnNACMZiZMdLrmjLlJ02dtXDtO4DEXcyj2q6k1oC30rjlYAPEVlO@TQ8@Fs/k2VDXdRzo/SHMfoZm2wuw14@35XkPdmHRzesN8SUSlZzSm13D5TWTEhKDwNvq2yztq8PNu9SwFT5kUYZOQ7z6XZic26k76Mgjl/7@As)

**Usage**:

```python
     # No IEEE 754 format rounding
In:  round_string('14.225',2)
Out: '14.23'

     # Trailing zeros
In:  round_string('123.4',5)
Out: '123.40000'

In: round_string('99.9',0)
Out: '100'

    # Negative values
In: round_string('-99.9',0)
Out: '-100'

In: round_string('1',0)
Out: '1'

    # No unnecessary decimal point
In: round_string('1.',0)
Out: '1'

    # No unnecessary decimal point
In: round_string('1.0',0)
Out: '1'

In:  for i in range(8): 
         print(round_string('123456789.987654321',i))
Out: 123456790
     123456790.0
     123456789.99
     123456789.988
     123456789.9877
     123456789.98765
     123456789.987654
     123456789.9876543
```

## Task

**Input argument 1**: a string containing

- at least one digit (`0`, `1`, `2`, `3`, `4`, `5`,`6`, `7`, `8`, `9`),
- at most one decimal point (`.`) which must be preceded by at least one digit,
- an optional minus (`-`) as first character.

**Input argument 2**: a non-negative integer

**Output**: the correctly rounded (base 10) string

rounding = [Round half away from zero](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rounding#Tie-breaking)

This is a [code-golf](/questions/tagged/code-golf). The lowest number of bytes wins!

Comment: @KevinCruijssen 1) You do not need to stick to strings in the body of your implementation and are allowed to use built-in rounding. Unfortunately (for the question) the IEEE 754 standard is a widely used standard and thus built-in rounding will not result in the desired behavior. 2) Ok, wasn't aware of the sandbox.

Comment: TI-Basic: `round(A,B` 5 bytes

Comment: @JulianLachniet Actually no, the input number is a string so maybe `round(expr(Str0,B` but then you need to convert that back into a string representation for output.

Comment: Regarding the second input argument: `0` is not a positive integer, it is "non-negative".

Comment: @Timtech `toString(round(expr(Str0),B`

Comment: I assume we add trailing zeros if needed? Could you perhaps add a test case for `123.4 & 5 --> 123.40000`? Or can we assume the second input will never be larger than the amount of decimals after the point in the first input?

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Added the example (trailing zeros). Is it possible to make the Python code interactive like Javascript on StackExchange?

Comment: @Matthias Unless you can integrate the Python with the JavaScript (I've never programmed Python, and barely JS, so I honestly don't know if it's possible) no. But you could always add a [Try it online](https://tio.run/nexus) link with your test code. EDIT: Also, it's usually better to wait at least a couple of days until you accept an answer.

Comment: @KevinCruijssen Thanks never used TIO before, but very handy.

Comment: @JonathanAllan Edit: added rounding explicitly

Comment: Related: [Round to n Sig Figs](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/93547/round-to-n-sig-figs)

Comment: Several answers seem to use `printf` and *doubles*, but they'll all fail with enough digits before or after the decimal dot. Can we assume any size/precision limits for the input?

Comment: @Dennis: No limitations are specified, so all sizes (Input argument 1) and precision (Input argument 2) sould be supported (as long as your underlying memory system does not become a bottleneck).

Comment: Can the inputs be taken in any order?

Comment: For the record, base 10! is an exceedingly odd base to choose.

Comment: @BasicSunset order is as specified and fixed

Comment: @Jules it is base 10. Since the initial solutions just used the default rounding without paying attention to the underlying binary implementation, I added an exclamation mark. But since this is confusing, I will remove it.

Comment: Interesting, thanks for the tip @JulianLachniet, didn't notice they added that to the CE calcs.

Comment: @Timtech Funny, because I don't have a CE myself ;). This drives my crazy. Also, what is "IEEE"

Comment: @JulianLachniet https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IEEE_floating_point

Comment: @JulianLachniet IEEE is an organization which specifies a.o. standards such as the IEEE 754 standard for floating points which has a huge impact on hardware and software. Basically it deals with the tradeoff between the number of bits for the mantissa (impacts the precision of the floating point numbers) and exponent (impacts the range of the floating point numbers)

Comment: Is `123.4` valid output for `round_string('123.4',5)`? Is `123456790.` valid output for `round_string('123456789.987654321',0)`?

Comment: @Dennis 1) `round_string('123.4',5)` = `'123.40000'` 2) `round_string('123456789.987654321',0)` = `'123456790'`

Comment: You should clarify that in your post. Examples do not count as part of the specification.

Comment: Also, since we have to support negative numbers, there should be negative number in the test cases, preferably ones that check for correct implementation of *round half away from zero*.

Comment: @Dennis updated

Comment: Were you not a bit quick on the accept trigger?

Comment: @Adám indeed. First thought I needed to manually verify the Wonder version and now there is the APL one which is even shorter. I guess we now reached the limit unless some language has a one byte built-in.

Comment: @Matthias APL has a built-in `⍕`, if you allow numeric input. Takes number as right argument and precision as left argument.

Comment: May I suggest you add some test cases? Currently my code works correctly for every single one of your test cases. But it fails on test cases like `987654321.666666666; 7`, `987654321.666666666; 8`, `987654321.666666666; 9`.

Comment: @Matthias Can we take input as a number?

Comment: @Adám only the second argument

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## [APL (Dyalog)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 4 bytes

Dyalog APL uses enough internal precision.

```apl
⎕⍕⍎⍞
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog#fYy7EcMgDEB7pmACDoT4LeRV7AZ3KZMVvINH0SIE4gtHgk86CtB7D9rWpdD@oFzPTvlVaFuL/MwiDCoAJ0BSfsr2sKIjsAqFu0i76zqdpqSS0Bcc1ucxgPMYkfnq3EbpeQcWnQ@x/huDd2ihdxdJmnXNr6t4G0a7kcTq9l@PkfVx8kNgAzcH3rGFvyuQTcJtYt8)

`⍎⍞` execute string input

`⎕⍕` get numeric input and use that as precision for formatting

Comment: Why is this 4 instead of 8 bytes?

Comment: @Matthias Because [Dyalog APL has a SBCS](https://tio.run/nexus/apl-dyalog-classic#fYy7EcMgDEB7pmACDoT4LeRV7AZ3KZMVvINH0SIE4gtHgk86CtB7D9rWpdD@oFzPTvlVaFuL/MwiDCoAJ0BSfsr2sKIjsAqFu0i76zqdpqSS0Bcc1ucxgPMYkfnq3EbpeQcWnQ@x/huDd2ihdxdJmnXNr6t4G0a7kcTq9l@PkfVx8kNgAzcH3rGFvyuQTcJtYt8)

Answer (score 5):

## Perl, <s>22</s> 20 bytes

```perl
printf"%.*f",pop,pop
```

Using:

```
perl -e 'printf"%.*f",pop,pop' 123456789.987654321 3
```

It is Dada’s version of code. Previous:

```perl
printf"%*2\$.*f",@ARGV
```

Comment: `printf"%.*f",pop,pop` should work

Answer (score 5):

## PHP, <s>33</s> 31 bytes

PHP rounds correctly too (at least on 64 bit):

```php
printf("%.$argv[2]f",$argv[1]);
```

takes input from command line arguments. Run with `-r`.

## PHP, no built-ins, 133 bytes

```php
[,$n,$r]=$argv;if($p=strpos(_.$n,46))for($d=$n[$p+=$r],$n=substr($n,0,$p-!$r);$d>4;$n[$p]=(5+$d=$n[$p]-4)%10)$p-=$n[--$p]<"/";echo$n;
```

Run with `-nr` or [test it online](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e2b9c11b733f4d151d14f055112527645a19cf58).

**breakdown**

```php
[,$n,$r]=$argv;             // import arguments
if($p=strpos(_.$n,46))      // if number contains dot
    for($d=$n[$p+=$r],          // 1. $d= ($r+1)-th decimal 
        $n=substr($n,0,$p-!$r); // 2. cut everything behind $r-th decimal
        $d>4;                   // 3. loop while previous decimal needs increment
        $n[$p]=(5+$d=$n[$p]-4)%10   // B. $d=current digit-4, increment current digit
    )
        $p-=$n[--$p]<"/";           // A. move cursor left, skip dot
echo$n;
```

A null byte doesn´t work; so I have to use `substr`.

Comment: You can write `"%.$argv[2]f"` instead of `"%.{$argv[2]}f"`, saving 2 bytes.

Answer (score 4):

## Python, <s>114</s>  <s>105</s> <s>103</s> <s>96</s> <s>91</s> 89 bytes

Saved 5 bytes thanks to *Kevin Cruijssen*
Saved 2 bytes thanks to *Krazor*

```python
from decimal import*
d=Decimal
lambda x,y:d(x).quantize(d('0.'[y>0]+'1'*y),ROUND_HALF_UP)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#TYtNC4IwAEDv@xW7bbMxdDq/wCCQ6BAVgacIWU1joNOGgfrnLehQ7/h4b6lt10JV3XUrG6jbvrODA1SWfw2os0a2NyXhSKdU4ZGw50uaQc8VVhi5DF2mtXtdIQ85E6HnY3HIy91mvy2LE1l6q82Aa4y8gHEuEOWEgLqzcIbaQCvNo8IxSQH88Gu5H4gwihOWxFEoAp97iM6f8b9gAaKCkOUN)

Comment: `from decimal import *` and removing the three `d.` is 4 bytes shorter.

Comment: You could also do `d=Decimal` and `d() `, which would save another 5. (Might be wrong, very sleepy)

Comment: @Krazor: Unless I did it wrong it saved me 2 bytes. Thanks!

Comment: Woops, that's what I've meant. Will leave my sleepy thoughts up anyways.

Answer (score 4):

### REXX, 24 bytes

```
arg n p
say format(n,,p)
```

Since REXX always uses text representation of numbers, correct rounding of numbers is free.

[Try it online!](https://tio.tryitonline.nz/nexus/rexx#@59YlK6Qp1DAVZxYqZCWX5SbWKKRp6NToPn//39DEz0jI1MFIwA)

Comment: Wow. nice abuse of the language.

Comment: Does REXX have an online compiler?

Comment: It's (mainly) an interpreted language.

Comment: [Try it online!](https://tio.tryitonline.nz/nexus/rexx#@59YlK6Qp1DAVZxYqZCWX5SbWKKRp6NToPn//39DEz0jI1MFIwA "Rexx (Regina) – TIO Nexus")

Answer (score 4):

### Ruby 2.3, 12 + 45 = 57

Uses the `BigDecimal` built-in, but it needs to be required before use, which is cheaper to do as a flag.

the flag: `-rbigdecimal`

the function:

```
->(s,i){BigDecimal.new(s).round(i).to_s('f')}
```

Ruby 2.3 by default uses `ROUND_HALF_UP`

Answer (score 4):

## Javascript (ES6), 44 bytes

```
n=>p=>(Math.round(n*10**p)/10**p).toFixed(p)
```

#### Try it online:

```js
const f = n=>p=>(Math.round(n*10**p)/10**p).toFixed(p)

console.log(f('14.225')(2));

[...Array(8).keys()].map(i=>console.log(f('123456789.987654321')(i)))

console.log(f('123.4')(5))
```

Answer (score 3):

## TI-Basic, <s>53</s> 16 bytes

TI-Basic does not use IEEE and the below method works for 0-9 (inclusive) decimal positions.

```
Prompt Str1,N
toString(round(expr(Str1),N
```

Thanks to @JulianLachniet for showing that CE calcs have the `toString(` command which I was not aware of (Color Edition calcs OS 5.2 or higher are required).

P.S. I did have a second line with `sub(Str1,1,N+inString(Str1,".` but then I realized it was useless.

Comment: How is `N` used?

Comment: @Matthias Thanks for catching that typo! I accidentally removed the last three bytes with my previous edit

Answer (score 3):

## Java 7, <s>77</s> <s>72</s> 71 bytes

```
<T>T c(T n,int d){return(T)"".format("%."+d+"f",new Double(n+""));}
```

-1 byte thanks to *@cliffroot*

**72-byte answer:**

```
String c(String n,int d){return n.format("%."+d+"f",new Double(n));}
```

Unlike Python, Java already rounds correctly and already returns a String when you use `String.format("%.2f", aDouble)` with the `2` replaced with the amount of decimals you want.

EDIT/NOTE: Yes, I'm aware `new Float(n)` is 1 byte shorter than `new Double(n)`, but apparently it fails for the test cases with `123456789.987654321`. [See this test code regarding Double vs Float.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#@5@ck1hcrOBbzaWgUFCalJOZrFBcklgCpMryM1MUchMz8zSCS4oy89KjYxUSNUHKFBSCK4tLUnP18ktL9AqAUiU5MDV6aflFuYklGkqqesZpSjoKeanlCi75QGNTNZQMjYxNTM3MLSz1LC3MzUxNjI0MlTQ1Na1JN9EtJx8kgsfAWq7a//8B)

**Explanation:**

```
<T> T c(T n, int d){               // Method with generic-T & integer parameters and generic-T return-type (generic-T will be String in this case)
  return (T)"".format("%."+d+"f",  //  Return the correctly rounded output as String
    new Double(n+""));             //  After we've converted the input String to a decimal
}                                  // End of method
```

**Test code:**

[Try it here.](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#jZDBaoNAEIbvPsUwUNhl7WI2mihJeuq1p3grPWzVlAVdg44pJfjsdoQUehIPw8DMxzfDPxW17Xt4g3sA0JMlV8Axf8mhEDn40HmCUt67iobOi1wi6kvbNZYEPmlUpcILhr76htd2@Kwr4RWilIcxYNuVJ2x7SG@tK6Gxzoszdc5/vX@AlfNRgPNPT1Wj24H0lVdUe1EI3MTamARDMCxc4sxWx4wly1iW6YypaJl6XodtViB6DRP9hzhZMQfu4ATRgdsRUm5KPXJaSCBOdvuUX0/3uyTemvk/96cdg7nGafoF)

```
class M{
  static <T>T c(T n,int d){return(T)"".format("%."+d+"f",new Double(n+""));}

  public static void main(String[] a){
    System.out.println(c("14.225", 2));
    System.out.println(c("123.4", 5));
    System.out.println(c("99.9", 0));
    System.out.println(c("-99.9", 0));
    System.out.println(c("1", 0));
    System.out.println(c("1.", 0));
    System.out.println(c("1.0", 0));
    for(int i = 0; i < 8; i++){
      System.out.println(c("123456789.987654321", i));
    }
  }
}
```

**Output:**

```
14.23
123.40000
100
-100
1
1
1
123456790
123456790.0
123456789.99
123456789.988
123456789.9877
123456789.98765
123456789.987654
123456789.9876543
```

Comment: One byte shorter:
`<T>T c(T n,int d){return(T)"".format("%."+d+"f",new Double(n+""));}`

Comment: This solution [doesn't work](https://tio.run/nexus/java-openjdk#bY5BS8NAEIXv/oohIOzasFi1aUvozYugXnIsOYybbTuSTMLupFVCfntMMXrKnN774L15VDW1F/jEM5pWqDR3qS0xBHjrgqCQHTLxxEewahIcEwsUuvNOWs/A5lD7CkVFtyZaFIvoEMXsLvBctx@lU6x12g/NqMnCbyWcayqgQuKpc5@j7jKLzM4D7a7pyansO4irDLFOLyca@8icMLy7L3kldkrrDndk@N@b0JQ0boFIp1O2bsU04xspWVmF@/s8fmFxR@dNgz640Yx0mevr0r4ftpt1snp6fFia5O9gdTNHk1m6nqWbWbr9AQ). Though the example is potentially a round half-even/away-0 issue, floating point errors do occur and OP has since clarified that arbitrary precision should be supported.

Comment: In fact, you fail the example cases in the question which you reproduced here: `123456789.987654321, 4` should be `123456789.9877`, not `123456789.9876`

Answer (score 3):

## BASH, <s>26</s> <s>23</s> 21 bytes

```
bc<<<"scale=$2;$1/1"
```

### usage

save to round_string.sh, chmod +x round_string.sh

```
./round_string.sh 23456789.987654321 3
```

edit:no need to load library

Comment: Explanation: bc uses arbitrary precission, create a here doc with '<<<' contaning the value of scale as the second parameter and the first parameter divided by 1 to force scale interpretation.

Comment: This gives `14.22` for the input `14.225 2`, and not `14.23`

Answer (score 3):

## AHK, 25 bytes

```
a=%1%
Send % Round(a,%2%)
```

Again I am foiled by the inability of AHK to use passed in parameters directly in functions that accept either a variable name or a number. If I replace `a` with `1` in the `Round` function, it uses the value `1`. If I try `%1%`, it tries to use the first argument's *contents* as a variable name, which doesn't work. Having to set it as another variable first cost me 6 bytes.

Answer (score 3):

### Batch, 390 bytes

```
@echo off
set s=%1
set m=
if %s:~,1%==- set m=-&set s=%s:~1%
set d=%s:*.=%
if %d%==%s% (set d=)else call set s=%%s:.%d%=%%
for /l %%i in (0,1,%2)do call set d=%%d%%0
call set/ac=%%d:~%2,1%%/5
call set d=00%s%%%d:~,%2%%
set z=
:l
set/ac+=%d:~-1%
set d=%d:~,-1%
if %c%==10 set c=1&set z=%z%0&goto l
set d=%m%%d:~2%%c%%z%
if %2==0 (echo %d%)else call echo %%d:~,-%2%%.%%d:~-%2%%
```

Explanation. Starts by extracting the sign, if applicable. Then, splits the number into integer and fraction digits. The fraction is padded with `n+1` zeros to ensure it has more than `n` digits. The `n`th (zero-indexed) digit is divided by 5, and this is the initial carry. The integer and `n` fraction digits are concatenated, and the carry added character by character. (The extra zeros guard against carry ripple.) After the carry stops rippling the number is reconstructed and any decimal point inserted.

Answer (score 2):

### Python (2/3), 394 bytes

```
def rnd(s,p):
    m=s[0]=='-'and'-'or''
    if m:s=s[1:]
    d=s.find('.')
    l=len(s)
    if d<0:
        if p>0:d=l;l+=1;s+='.'
        else:return m+s
    e=(d+p+1)-l
    if e>0:return m+s+'0'*e
    o=''
    c=0
    for i in range(l-1,-1,-1):
        x=s[i]
        if i<=d+p:
            if i!=d:
                n=int(x)+c
                if n>9:n=0;c=1 
                else:c=0
                o+=str(n)
            else:
                if p>0:o+=x
        if i==d+p+1:c=int(x)>4
    if c:o+='1'
    return m+''.join(reversed(o))
```

Works for arbitrary precision numbers.

Comment: Hey, and welcome to PPCG! However, this isn't golfed. There's a _lot_ of whitespace you can remove. Answers on this site are required to be golfed, sorry.

Comment: Just some things (there is likely a lot more)... The function name can be one byte. The first line can use `s[0]<'0'` and could also use string multiplication, `m='-'*(s[0]<'0')`. Lines without any block statement spans can be joined together with `;` (e.g. `o='';c=0`). Some `if` statements could be probably be replaced by list indexing to further reduce the need for line breaks and tabs. The final line could use a slice, `o[::-1]`, instead of `reversed(o)` and the `''.join` is redundant. You may well also be able to rewrite it to avoid the need for multiple `return` statements.

Comment: ... if you're interested there are [tips for golfing in Python here](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/54/tips-for-golfing-in-python).

Answer (score 2):

### JavaScript (ES6), 155 bytes

```
(s,n)=>s.replace(/(-?\d+).?(.*)/,(m,i,d)=>i+'.'+(d+'0'.repeat(++n)).slice(0,n)).replace(/([0-8]?)([.9]*?)\.?(.)$/,(m,n,c,r)=>r>4?-~n+c.replace(/9/g,0):n+c)
```

Explanation: The string is first normalised to contain a `.` and `n+1` decimal digits. The trailing digit, any preceding `9`s or `.`s, and any preceding digit, are then considered. If the last digit is less than 5 then it and any immediately preceding `.` are simply removed but if it is greater than 5 then the `9`s are changed to `0`s and the previous digit incremented (or 1 prefixed if there was no previous digit).

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) + SymPy, 54 bytes

```python
from sympy import*
lambda s,p:'%.*f'%(p,S(s).round(p))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/nexus/python3#XY3LCoMwEEXX5itmI0kkDZomvqBf0W03Fk0JNA@iXfj1VhQsdnnOnblXww0ey7uzz76DkYUWpzzTOCWB3clIefQf15NAKdLRWxhnG2YwNvg4ZUs/aNgP1k/aoiRE4yaiN6QI7RkuJBdCYSboYcSVS8zUIZqGN5jlB1/@RXECfqZ8Q@0jGDAOYudeA6lpCyj5DUpVVvXaWlelklexFhq6fAE)

Answer (score 1):

## J, <s>22</s> 17 bytes

```
((10 j.[)]@:":".)

NB.    2    ((10 j.[)]@:":".)   '12.45678'
NB.    12.46
```

Thanks to @Conor O'Brien for correcting my understanding of the rules.

```
t=:4 :'(10 j.x)":".y'

    NB.    Examples
    NB.    4 t'12.45678'
    NB.    12.4568
    NB.    4 t'12.456780'
    NB.    12.4568
    NB.    4 t'12.4567801'
    NB.    12.4568
    NB.    2 t'12.45678'
    NB.      12.46
    NB.    2 t'12.4567801'
    NB.      12.46
    NB.    2 (10 j.[)":". '_12.4567801'
    NB.     _12.46

format    
    x t y
where x is a digit number of decimal places required and y
is the character string containing the value to be rounded.
```

Comment: The challenge requires you to take the number of digits after the decimal point to round to N decimals, not N points of precision. As such, `2 t '1234.456'` should give `1234.46` instead of `6 t '1234.456'`

Answer (score 1):

## Scala, 44 bytes

```
(s:String,p:Int)=>s"%.${p}f"format s.toFloat
```

Test:

```
scala> var x = (s:String,p:Int)=>s"%.${p}f"format s.toFloat
x: (String, Int) => String = <function2>

scala> x("14.225",2)
res13: String = 14.23
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Wonder](https://github.com/wonderlang/wonder), 10 bytes

```
@@fix#1E#0
```

Usage:

```
@@fix#1E#0
```

Set decimal precision and add trailing zeros if necessary.

Comment: Is there a TIO for this one?

Comment: No there isn't, but the installation is pretty easy. Make sure you have Node.js (v6+), and `npm i -g wonderlang`. Use the `wonder` command to fire up the REPL, and paste the code in.