# Round like a Zero

Tags: code-golf, math

## Goal

Given an input number, round it off to the nearest number with one significant figure.

## Requirements

### Input

- A floating point number.
- Assume the input number results in an output within the data type's limits (ie. ignore overflow errors.)
- 0 is an invalid input.
- Numbers that cannot be accurately represented in the floating point data type (eg. `"0.35"` being stored as `0.3499999`) do not have to be supported.

### Output

- The nearest number that consists of one non-zero digit and any number of zero digits.
- The result must support negative numbers and fractional numbers.
- When the input lies exactly between two possible outputs, round away from zero.

#### Presentation

The focus is on the calculation rather than the presentation.  The output may be a floating point data type.  It may be text either in full or in scientific notation.  If you find a loophole where presenting a certain way reduces your byte count, kudos to you!

#### Examples

```
9
-3000
.2
0.2
-.2
7e12
5e-15
1e0
```

## Test Cases

```
Input     Output
1         1
10        10
17        20
99        100
54321     50000
56789     60000
-123      -100
-789      -800
0.23      0.2
0.25      0.3
-0.25     -0.3
4.56e23   5e23
4.56e-23  5e-23
```

## Scoring

The code with the least byte-count after one week wins.

Comment: I think "one significant figure" is the phrase you're looking for.

Comment: @SteveBennett, agreed.  High school science was too long ago.

Comment: The rounding rule for 0 is pretty weird.

Comment: @xnor, you're right.  0 is closer to 0.0001 than 1.  I think 0 should simply be invalid.

Comment: Yeah, and it doesn't match the goal statement.

Comment: Can we output trailing zeros after decimal i.e. `-800.0` instead of `-800`?

Comment: @officialaimm, yes.  Presentation is not important.

Comment: Darn, Negative numbers screw over my solution.

Comment: Duplicate of https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/93547/round-to-n-sig-figs ?

Comment: @Neil Hmm...I don't think this prohibits output ending in `.0` like that one does.

Comment: @officialaimm I would think not. `-800` has one significant figure, but `-800.0` has four.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 3 bytes

```
1&V
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/31At7P9/S0sA) Or [verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8N9QLey/S8h/Qy5DAy5Dcy5LSy5TE2MjQy5TM3MLSy5dQyNjLl0Qy0APyAISply6YNJEz9QsFSgEpnWNjAE).

Test case `0.25` fails for the compiler running in Octave on TIO, but works in Matlab on Windows:

[image]

The different behaviour is caused by Octave's/Matlab's `sprintf` function using either "banker's rounding" or ".5 away from zero" rounding, depending on platform. More information and tests can be found [here](https://savannah.gnu.org/bugs/index.php?51515).

---

For **6 bytes**,

```
1t3$Yo
```

works both on Octave and on Matlab. [Verify all test cases](https://tio.run/##y00syfmf8N@wxFglMv@/S8h/Qy5DAy5Dcy5LSy5TE2MjQy5TM3MLSy5dQyNjLl0Qy0APyAISply6YNJEz9QsFSgEpnWNjAE).

Comment: "banker's rounding" is pretty much what made me delete my Jelly answer. >_<

Comment: @EriktheOutgolfer Yes, I figured out that was the reason too. I'm lucky that Matlab doesn't do that :-D

Answer (score 12):

## [C# (.NET Core)](https://www.microsoft.com/net/core/platform), <s>19</s> 12 bytes

```cs
n=>$"{n:G1}"
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##jc69CsIwFEDhvU8RxKEFG@xPqrW2i6CLTg7ONb2VQL2B3lSQ0mePoLga9w/OkRRK3YOVXU3E9OiRqY2S7KFVw061Qj8YvfOTDNz5fkC5bfRw7WBBpld4q1hbWiyr@WzEzSGaZrbwvnqnkXQH/NIrA0eF4Le@SJM4CoLilwlFtlrnDpS7wJLHiZsI18sfJuUiA2fsrcIPmyb7Ag)

Examples:

```cs
Input     Output
----------------
 54321     5E+04
-56789    -6E+04
 99        1E+02
 0.23      0.2
 0.25      0.3
-0.25     -0.3
 4.56e23   5E+23
 4.56e-23  5E-23
```

With the new versions of C# we also got shorter ways to achieve this, as Calculuswhiz wisely noted in the comments.

Comment: Shorter way to format: `n=>$"{n:G1}"`

Answer (score 9):

### Javascript, 19 bytes

```
x=>x.toPrecision(1)
```

Comment: This doesn’t satisfy the specification on `0` or `25`.

Comment: Interesting. The spec for `0` doesn't make sense to me. But the `0.35` thing...looks like Javascript is trying to avoid bias in rounding, but the spec wants the bias.

Comment: Hey, you changed your comment - you wrote `0.35` not `25` before. I think it does satisfy the spec for 25 - it returns "3e+1" which seems right to me.

Comment: Sorry, I changed it from `0.35` because `0.35` has no exact floating-point representation. The behavior must be browser-dependent; I get `25` ↦ `2e+1` in Firefox.

Comment: Yup, I get those two different results in Chrome vs Firefox. Wow.

Comment: Not sure what to do about the 0.35 thing then? The spec says the input is "a floating point number". So it's necessarily language dependent whether "the input lies exactly between two possible outputs"?

Comment: My interpretation would be that “`0.35`” represents a floating-point number that’s slightly less than the mathematical value 35/100, so it’s fine to round it down. Now that the awful specification for `0` has been edited out, this answer seems fine if you label it “JavaScript (Chrome)”, unless I’m missing something else.

Comment: I'll accept that floating point is an imperfect system.  The input is a floating point data type, and the data type cannot represent `0.35`, so it's an impossible input in this circumstance.

Comment: Maybe if I wait long enough every possible input will be ruled invalid... :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Retina](https://github.com/m-ender/retina), <s>63</s> 62 bytes

```
1`[1-9]
$*#
#\.?[5-9]
#$&
T`d`0`#[\d.]+
0(\.?)#{10}
1$1
#+
$.0
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##LY67DsIwDEX3@xspiIdi2W3dkomRH2ArSEGiAwsDYkN8e7ETMpxznVxLec3vx/O2rDanvEieJKYrml1AuNBxUp9Cs8Y53zPnMF3udN2DN/a4DR/hL6QRhD0a4mURCENGpATtu1agw3hIiNJ2iJ6YLBkUsbAnHeZ2rI4WhETm5EVm7nQ8DN7nlGw0wgOVhOra/bsoUaHLaEK9tsOVXJe1V3eVU8lhf0GZeuUC/gE)

Comment: Apparently you don't have to worry about trailing zeros so you can remove the last stage completely (although I'm impressed by it, it's not every day you see three question marks in the space of four characters).

Comment: Unfortunately this answer appears to fail for `0.99`.

Comment: Also fails for `0.099` etc. My attempt at a fix: [Try it online!](https://tio.run/##FYu9CsJADID3vEUxldwFQ6I4hBsy9iF6hQp1cHEQt@Kzn9f1@/k8v6/3o00jrdBsne3iC2AuQIWrRCKa7x1FqltOgHLrDg3lillB6UjKbvoDQ1Yo3JMzVCHhSBHKFEPd@ngyzILWmoo7qKj7Hw "Retina – Try It Online")

Comment: Also fails for `99.99`, `100.001`, ...

Comment: Still wrong for `0.099`, sorry. On the bright side I think you can remove the `+` after the `;` on the third line.

Comment: New algorithm + more test cases. Should catch everything now

Comment: You'd think so, but this actually fails for the existing test case `4.56e27`, as well as also other cases such as `1.11e99`.

Comment: Man I really shouldn't do Retina before I sleep (or, for that matter, use a string-based language for  a math problem)

Comment: Don't worry, I'm still impressed... my attempt was over 100 bytes!

Comment: Perhaps you should go to sleep, and not worry about fixing `0.5` until you're less tired?

Comment: @Neil `0.5` looks good for me. [Try it online](https://tio.run/##K0otycxL/O@uqpHA9T8mhUtFS9maKyRBOUEtIVVPm8s6Rs9eudq0lktZRY0rxBAoHp@gYW9jq6xpHa1srRerzaWhXKOmqWXNpaJs@P@/gZ4pl4GegSmXIZChC@LpAlkA)

Comment: No, `0.5` should be unchanged...

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), 45 bytes

```php
<?=round($x=$argv[1],-floor(log10(abs($x))));
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@P/fxt62KL80L0VDpcJWJbEovSzaMFZHNy0nP79IIyc/3dBAIzGpGCipCQTW////N9AzMgUA)

Same method as my python 2 answer.

Also seems to correctly handle `0.35`, which puts it a peg above the JS answer too :D

Comment: Interestingly, I think your deleted Python 3 answer may work in Python 2.

Comment: Tested, and it does! Edited and undeleted the python answer now

Answer (score 2):

## T-SQL, 27 bytes

```sql
SELECT FORMAT(i,'G1')FROM t
```

Using the same .Net formatting code as [Carlos Alejo's C# answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/133506/70172). Input is from *float* column **i** in pre-existing table **t**, [per our IO standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341)

Test cases:

```
Input         Output
------------ --------
1             1
10            1E+01
17            2E+01
99            1E+02
54321         5E+04
56789         6E+04
-123         -1E+02
-789         -8E+02
0.23          0.2
0.25          0.3
-0.25        -0.3
4.56E+23      5E+23
4.56E-23      5E-23
```

(Pretty handy that I can pre-load the input table with all these values and run them at once.)

Answer (score 2):

## Excel 2016, 36

- Input A1.
- A2: `=10^INT(LOG10(ABS(A1`
- Result: `=A2*ROUND(A1/A2,`

Answer (score 1):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 62 bytes

```python
lambda x:round(x,-int(floor(log10(abs(x)))))
from math import*
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqii/NC9Fo0JHNzOvRCMtJz@/SCMnP93QQCMxqVijQhMEuNKK8nMVchNLMhQycwvyi0q0/hcUAZUrpGnomltYanLBeEamCLaBnpExCg9JzkTP1CwVKP3/v4GesSkA)

Not used to python golfing, but this works.

Fails on `0.35` due to floating point inaccuracies.

Thanks to Anders Kaseorg for pointing out that this works correctly in Python 2

Comment: The output for `0.25` is supposed to be `0.3`.

Comment: @AndersKaseorg I'm not sure why, but I can only assume it's due to the same floating-point inaccuracies as the Javascript answer.

Comment: Hmm wait 25 has the same problem... weird.

Comment: For anyone wondering, Python 2's `round` rounds away from zero while Python 3 rounds to even, that's why this works in Py2 but not 3.

Comment: you can golf few bytes using `log(x,10)` instead of `log10(abs(x))`.

Comment: @AlixEisenhardt [Apparently not](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUaHCqii/NC9Fo0JHNzOvRCMtJz@/SCMnPx0oYGigCQRcaUX5uQq5iSUZCpm5BflFJVr/C4qAShXSNHTNLSw1uWA8I1ME20DPyBiFhyRnomdqlgqU/v/fQM/YFAA)

Comment: Oh, my bad. Is seems that it's not working with negative inputs.

Answer (score 1):

## [Guile](https://www.gnu.org/software/guile/), 23 bytes

```scm
(format #t"~,0e"(read))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K07OSM1N1U0vzcxJ/f9fIy2/KDexREG5RKlOxyBVSaMoNTFFU/P/fwM9I1MA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 5](https://www.perl.org/), 15 bytes

```perl
printf"%.1g",<>
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0gtyjH9/7@gKDOvJE1JVc8wXUnHxu7/fxM9U7NUI2MA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Zsh](http://zsh.sourceforge.net/), 14 bytes

Port of the perl answer. [Try it Online!](https://tio.run/##qyrO@P@/oCgzryRNQVXPMF1BxfD////G8aYGBvEGBgZ6QGwIAA)

```bash
printf %.1g $1
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 24 bytes

```forth
: f 1 set-precision f. ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##TctNDoIwEAXgfU/xwr5NfyhYSbwMTJWNTAqev1ZjpbOZfPPmxS0dD3mPn5XzFREGOx2SE83rvm5PRIWpBIy4vBhGw0KXY1oYqgPkDV1pzQmTMIQ6LIymBmODEBr43tlfr2AYL6FCGuuovsl/UKBVkxT48@0Ui175gaxrIL/i/AY)

Input is expected on the floating point stack. Output is to stdout

I don't like making changes to the global (for this instance) precision of the floating point output functions, but it saves a lot of bytes to not have to restore the previous value at the end. Does not output in engineering or scientific notation, regardless of input.

*Note: For some reason, the tio interpreter converts `0.25` to `0.2`, while my local installation converts `0.25` to `0.3`. I'm not entirely sure why this is, but since I get the correct result locally, I'm leaving my answer as-is*

```forth
: f                   \ start a new word definition
  1 set-precision     \ set the floating point output words to use 1 significant digit
  f.                  \ output the top of the floating point stack
;                     \ end the word definition
```