# Rounding Numbers

Tags: code-golf, approximation

## Task

Given a number between 0 and 1 and another integer, print the approximated value of the first number rounded off to the specified number of digits given by the second integer. For example, if the input is `0.3212312312 , 2` then the output is:

`0.32`

## Rules

- The number of digits after the dot should always equal the second input integer.
- The input will always be `([)number from 0-1 , integer above 0(])`
- Predefined round functions are allowed.
- The first input number will not have any trailing 0's
- Always use a dot for input and output. Commas are not allowed.
- Fractions are allowed as output with the notation `number/number` but try to just use a decimal notation.

[Trailing zero rule removed due to that i should have been faster]

- Rounding should always be done to the closest number so up if above 4 and down if under 5.

## Testcases

Input: 0.31231231231 , 1

Output:
0.3

Input: 0.1, 10

Output:
0.1000000000

Input: 0.01231231231 , 9

Output:
0.012312312

## Scoring:

This is code-golf. Shortest answer in bytes wins.

Suggestion for making this challenge better are appreciated. Have fun golfing!

EDIT:
definition of this challenge by Francisco Hahn: `shortest way to round a float X with precision N on each language`

### Leaderboard

Here is a Stack Snippet to generate both a regular leaderboard and an overview of winners by language.

```js
/* Configuration */

var QUESTION_ID = 166330; // Obtain this from the url
// It will be like https://XYZ.stackexchange.com/questions/QUESTION_ID/... on any question page
var ANSWER_FILTER = "!t)IWYnsLAZle2tQ3KqrVveCRJfxcRLe";
var COMMENT_FILTER = "!)Q2B_A2kjfAiU78X(md6BoYk";
var OVERRIDE_USER = 48934; // This should be the user ID of the challenge author.

/* App */

var answers = [], answers_hash, answer_ids, answer_page = 1, more_answers = true, comment_page;

function answersUrl(index) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/questions/" +  QUESTION_ID + "/answers?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + ANSWER_FILTER;
}

function commentUrl(index, answers) {
  return "https://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/answers/" + answers.join(';') + "/comments?page=" + index + "&pagesize=100&order=desc&sort=creation&site=codegolf&filter=" + COMMENT_FILTER;
}

function getAnswers() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: answersUrl(answer_page++),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      answers.push.apply(answers, data.items);
      answers_hash = [];
      answer_ids = [];
      data.items.forEach(function(a) {
        a.comments = [];
        var id = +a.share_link.match(/\d+/);
        answer_ids.push(id);
        answers_hash[id] = a;
      });
      if (!data.has_more) more_answers = false;
      comment_page = 1;
      getComments();
    }
  });
}

function getComments() {
  jQuery.ajax({
    url: commentUrl(comment_page++, answer_ids),
    method: "get",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    crossDomain: true,
    success: function (data) {
      data.items.forEach(function(c) {
        if (c.owner.user_id === OVERRIDE_USER)
          answers_hash[c.post_id].comments.push(c);
      });
      if (data.has_more) getComments();
      else if (more_answers) getAnswers();
      else process();
    }
  });  
}

getAnswers();

var SCORE_REG = /<h\d>\s*([^\n,]*[^\s,]),.*?(\d+)(?=[^\n\d<>]*(?:<(?:s>[^\n<>]*<\/s>|[^\n<>]+>)[^\n\d<>]*)*<\/h\d>)/;

var OVERRIDE_REG = /^Override\s*header:\s*/i;

function getAuthorName(a) {
  return a.owner.display_name;
}

function process() {
  var valid = [];
  
  answers.forEach(function(a) {
    var body = a.body;
    a.comments.forEach(function(c) {
      if(OVERRIDE_REG.test(c.body))
        body = '<h1>' + c.body.replace(OVERRIDE_REG, '') + '</h1>';
    });
    
    var match = body.match(SCORE_REG);
    if (match)
      valid.push({
        user: getAuthorName(a),
        size: +match[2],
        language: match[1],
        link: a.share_link,
      });
    
  });
  
  valid.sort(function (a, b) {
    var aB = a.size,
        bB = b.size;
    return aB - bB
  });

  var languages = {};
  var place = 1;
  var lastSize = null;
  var lastPlace = 1;
  valid.forEach(function (a) {
    if (a.size != lastSize)
      lastPlace = place;
    lastSize = a.size;
    ++place;
    
    var answer = jQuery("#answer-template").html();
    answer = answer.replace("{{PLACE}}", lastPlace + ".")
                   .replace("{{NAME}}", a.user)
                   .replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", a.language)
                   .replace("{{SIZE}}", a.size)
                   .replace("{{LINK}}", a.link);
    answer = jQuery(answer);
    jQuery("#answers").append(answer);

    var lang = a.language;
    if (/<a/.test(lang)) lang = jQuery(lang).text();
    
    languages[lang] = languages[lang] || {lang: a.language, user: a.user, size: a.size, link: a.link};
  });

  var langs = [];
  for (var lang in languages)
    if (languages.hasOwnProperty(lang))
      langs.push(languages[lang]);

  langs.sort(function (a, b) {
    if (a.lang > b.lang) return 1;
    if (a.lang < b.lang) return -1;
    return 0;
  });

  for (var i = 0; i < langs.length; ++i)
  {
    var language = jQuery("#language-template").html();
    var lang = langs[i];
    language = language.replace("{{LANGUAGE}}", lang.lang)
                       .replace("{{NAME}}", lang.user)
                       .replace("{{SIZE}}", lang.size)
                       .replace("{{LINK}}", lang.link);
    language = jQuery(language);
    jQuery("#languages").append(language);
  }

}
```

```css
body { text-align: left !important}

#answer-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

#language-list {
  padding: 10px;
  width: 290px;
  float: left;
}

table thead {
  font-weight: bold;
}

table td {
  padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.sstatic.net/codegolf/all.css?v=83c949450c8b">
<div id="answer-list">
  <h2>Leaderboard</h2>
  <table class="answer-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td></td><td>Author</td><td>Language</td><td>Size</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="answers">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<div id="language-list">
  <h2>Winners by Language</h2>
  <table class="language-list">
    <thead>
      <tr><td>Language</td><td>User</td><td>Score</td></tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody id="languages">

    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="answer-template">
    <tr><td>{{PLACE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
<table style="display: none">
  <tbody id="language-template">
    <tr><td>{{LANGUAGE}}</td><td>{{NAME}}</td><td>{{SIZE}}</td><td><a href="{{LINK}}">Link</a></td></tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: [*Very* closely related, potential duplicate.](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/q/93547/42963) Since my vote is a hammer, I won't vote to close as yet.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork It is closely related but not a duplicate as that one allows for other number ranges. Thanks for showing this to me though.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork That question is about rounding to significant figures, rather than decimal places.  This doesn't need any sort of handling for numbers like `0.0001`.

Comment: @AdmBorkBork as far as i see the other question handles significative values of the float, this one doesn't, but i can see this post as something like **shortest way to round a float X with precision N on each language**

Comment: Will the first number ever include trailing `0`s? (e.g. `0.80`)

Comment: @Shaggy It won't, ill add that to my challenge

Comment: (1) can `0` or `1` appear in the input? If so, are they provided with trailing `.`?

Comment: @user202729 added, thanks.

Comment: It is inadvisable to use "try" in a challenge specification. Either require it or do not require it.

Comment: Will we ever get something that rounds to 1, such as `0.999, 1`?

Comment: "Rounding should always be done to the closest number so up if above 4 and down if under 5." Most languages use the round-to-even standard (2.5 rounds to 2). If you enforce this requirement, I'm not sure any of the proposed solutions are correct.

Comment: Suggestion: test cases with rounding

Comment: Suggested test case: `0.02675, 4` (Breaks many existing answers)

Comment: @12Me21: As noted on said answers, `0.02675` is not a "real" number; the actual value is `0.02674999999999...`, so rounding down is correct here, regardless of rounding strategy.

Comment: @ShadowRanger of course `0.02675` is a real number (that unfortunately can't be represented accurately in binary). Requiring that `0.02675` should always be rounded down doesn't make much sense IMO. If you use a language that's clever enough to realize it should be rounded up when working in base-10, then you shouldn't be punished for it. I'd say optional rounding in case of floating point inaccuracies is the way to go here. `0.15 ≠ 0.1499...`.

Comment: @StewieGriffin: My point is not that it *should* do anything. I'm trying to point out that rounding down in such a language is correct (because the value isn't actually at the midway point), not that the (almost non-existent) set of languages with decimal based floating point should be penalized if they (correctly) round their exact values up. Really, making any sort of rounding guarantees near the midway point is a problem; as Benjamin notes, most languages use round-half-even as a strategy, so leaving the "ends in exactly 5" case as implementation dependent is probably the way to go.

Comment: @StewieGriffin: My other comments are a little more clear; sorry for being misleading in this one. In the languages that use IEE-754 binary64 floating point (the vast majority), 0.02675 doesn't exist, and they approximate it with a slightly smaller number. Defining rounding rules excessively strictly will effectively limit responses to languages with decimal floating point (and for many of them, bloat the answers since they default to binary64 and need libraries for decimal, e.g. Java's `BigDecimal` and Python's `decimal`).

Comment: If you choose to edit the spec after you already got answers, you should at least notify the answers that got invalid with a comment. (*Trailing zeroes should be added with for example 0.1, 10.* invalidates quite a few answers that rely on `round` builtins)

Answer (score 6):

## [APL (Dyalog Unicode)](https://www.dyalog.com/), 1 [byte](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9429/43319)<sup>[SBCS](https://github.com/abrudz/SBCS)</sup>

Anonymous tacit infix function (actually just a built-in). Takes number of decimals as left argument and fraction as right argument.

```apl
⍕
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##SyzI0U2pTMzJT////1Hv1P9pj9omPOrte9Q31dP/UVfzofXGj9omAnnBQc5AMsTDM/i/kUKagoGesZGhkTEYcRlCBGB8Y0MuQwOwkCGXJZg2QEgBAA)

[Documentation for dyadic `⍕`](http://help.dyalog.com/17.0/Content/Language/Primitive%20Functions/Format%20Dyadic.htm) ("Format By Specification").

Comment: I like how you treat that built-in so formally over TIO...

Comment: I'm not sure if this fits the challenge as this requires a f as input instead of a , (atleast on TIO)

Comment: @LucH APL is usually used in an interactive session (REPL). TIO's Code area contains the actual definition(s) while Input is the session where the "user" uses the function `f`.

Answer (score 5):

## [JavaScript (Node.js)](https://nodejs.org), 18 bytes

```javascript
a=>b=>a.toFixed(b)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osSyxOLsosKNHNy09J/Z9m@z/R1i7J1i5RryTfLbMiNUUjSfN/cn5ecX5Oql5OfrpGmoaCgZ6xoREMaWooGGpqcmEoMUBRYqmp@R8A)

Comment: lol,  this is just nice :)

Answer (score 4):

## [Japt](https://github.com/ETHproductions/japt), 2 bytes

```
xV
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/vyLs/38DPQNDI2MoUtBRMAIA)

**x** is the builtin for rounding to **n** decimals. We pass in **V** (Second input).

Comment: Okay... I don't  think this can be beat lol.

Comment: Dang it! Too slow!

Comment: https://tio.run/##y0osKPn/vyLs/38DPQNDI2MoUtBRMAIA maybe use that notation for input in your tio as your current version wasn't according to the challenge rules. (code is the same, just changed the input)

Comment: @LucH - that's irrelevant in Japt each comma *or* newline separated item is a separate input.

Comment: Fails on `0.02675, 4`

Comment: The challenge requires it to round up to `0.0268`

Comment: @12Me21 Good spot, a trailing 5 should indeed be rounded up. I don't know why japt rounds it down.

Answer (score 4):

## Japt, 2 bytes

Takes input as an array of 2 numbers.

```
rx
```

[Try it](https://ethproductions.github.io/japt/?v=1.4.5&code=cng=&input=WzAuMDEyMzEyMzEyMzEsOV0=)

`r`educes the array by rounding the first number to the number of decimals specified by the second.

Comment: Japt just seems to be too good for this challenge.

Comment: Upvoting this answer because it is smaller than the other Japt answer: this one uses only lowercase characters.

Answer (score 2):

## [PHP](https://php.net/), <s>47</s> 39 bytes

```php
function a($b,$c){return round($b,$c);}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jXwAk00rzkksy8/MUEjVUknRUkjWri1JLSovyFIryS/NSoGLWtf9TkzPygWoM9IwNjWBIQUfBUFNBT0EpJk/JmguuwgBFhSVCBZe93X8A)

Comment: How many languages are you going to golf this in? ;)

Comment: @LucH 2 is nothing try seeing Leaky's 10 answer combo :D

Comment: @LucH The challenge is too easy. xD sorry

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/questions/120052/try-to-make-a-square that one was easy and it blew up so that's why i also made this one.

Comment: Are you sure you can pass the arguments like that toa  php script?, it is my understanding that the values has to be on the `$argv` array as arguments for the script.

Comment: @LuisfelipeDejesusMunoz [`$argv`](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.argv.php) acording to the documentation the php script needs the input on `$argv`. About the function you can short a few bits by using `echo` instead of `return`

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 2](https://docs.python.org/2/), 24 bytes

-4 bytes thanks to ovs

```python
lambda a,b:"%%0.%sf"%b%a
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFRJ8lKSVXVQE@1OE1JNUk18X9BUWZeiUaahoGekYmOgomm5n8A)

Comment: Fails on `0.02675, 4`

Comment: @12Me21: Not relevant, since `0.02675` doesn't actually exist as an exact value in IEEE 754 binary64 floating point (which most languages use as the basis for floating point math; you'll get the same issues with Java, JavaScript, C#, C [compiler dependent], etc.). The closest value is something like `0.02674999999999999947`, with `0.02675` being a convenient shorthand. [Floating point math is broken from a human perspective](https://stackoverflow.com/q/588004/364696)

Comment: [24 bytes](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/qfZhvzPycxNyklUSFRJ8lKSVXVQE@1OE1JNUk18X9BUWZeiUaahoGekYmOgomm5n8A)

Comment: @ovs: Using more modern formatting (i.e. the `str.format` method, not printf-style formatting), you can get it down to 16 bytes (doesn't even require a `lambda`). [My second solution for Python 3](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166365/70305) will work identically in Python 2.7 (and only require two more bytes on Python 2.6, to add indices to the formatting placeholders).

Answer (score 2):

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) (produces rounded float, no trailing zeroes), 5 bytes

```python
round
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzvyi/NC/lf0FRZl6JRpqGgZ6RiY6CoabmfwA)

Python's [built-in `round` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#round) is defined to do exactly what the OP wants in the summary edited in later "round a float X with precision N", though without appending trailing zeroes (because it's still returning a `float`, and `float`s don't include information about their formatting).

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) (produces string form), 16 bytes

```python
'{:.{}f}'.format
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzX73aSq@6Nq1WXS8tvyg3seR/QVFmXolGmoaBnpGJjoKhpuZ/AA)

Formatting operations can use a nested specifier to allow one argument to define the precision of the other. Doesn't print it, but returns a formatted string with the specified precision.

## [Python 3](https://docs.python.org/3/) (prints string), 30 bytes

```python
lambda a,b:print(f'{a:.{b}f}')
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K6gsycjPM/6fZhvzPycxNyklUSFRJ8mqoCgzr0QjTb060UqvOqk2rVZd83@ahoGekYmOgqHmfwA)

Python 3.6+ f-strings save some characters here (couldn't use them without the wrapping function since we wouldn't know the names to use). Mostly included to demonstrate f-strings (obviously longer than other solutions).

Comment: `Note: The behavior of round() for floats can be surprising: for example, round(2.675, 2) gives 2.67 instead of the expected 2.68. This is not a bug: it’s a result of the fact that most decimal fractions can’t be represented exactly as a float. See Floating Point Arithmetic: Issues and Limitations for more information. `

Comment: @12Me21: This is a problem in *any* language based on IEEE binary floating point. If `2.675` doesn't really exist, it's just a shorter spelling of `2.6749999999999999996` or whatever, then you've rounded correctly. Python isn't unique here, it's just up front about the problem in the docs, where many languages don't bother to mention it.

Answer (score 1):

### PHP, 28 Bytes

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##K8go@G9jX5BRwKWSWJReZhttoGdsaARDOoax1lz2dkAVtkX5pXkpGmBF0QaxOhCGYaym9f//AA)

**Code**

```
<?=round($argv[0],$argv[1]);
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Forth (gforth)](http://www.complang.tuwien.ac.at/forth/gforth/Docs-html/), 26 bytes

Assuming decimal is on top of the floating point stack and precision is on the integer stack

```forth
: f dup 2 + swap 1 f.rdp ;
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##S8svKsnQTU8DUf//WymkKaSUFigYKWgrFJcnFigYKqTpFaUUKFj/N9AzNjSCoVSQhEJyEZeBHohtAOMYICuxBIv@BwA)

#### Explanation

`f.rdp` takes a float and 3 arguments from the integer stack:

1. the width of the output (answer uses `n+2` to account for 0 and decimal point)
2. the number of digits after the decimal (answer uses `n`)
3. the required number of significant figures in the input (answer uses 1, because floats with less significant figures are outputted in exponential notation)

#### Code explanation

```forth
dup 2 + swap 1        \ place n+2 n and 1 on top of the stack
f.rdp                 \ formats output
```

Answer (score 1):

## [Stax](https://github.com/tomtheisen/stax), 1 bytes

```
j
```

[Run and debug it](https://staxlang.xyz/#c=j&i=0.3212312312,+2%0A0.1,+10&a=1&m=2)

In stax, `j` is a built-in instruction that performs the required rounding.

Answer (score 1):

## T-SQL, 24 bytes

```sql
SELECT STR(f,20,d)FROM t
```

[Per our input standards](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2447/default-for-code-golf-input-output-methods/5341#5341), input is taken via pre-existing table **t** with float **f** and integer **d**.

The [function `STR()`](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/str-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) is shorter and more convenient than either a `CAST` or a `ROUND`.

You didn't specify, so I assumed that 20 digits would be more than sufficient. If not, that hard-coded value can be increased.

Answer (score 1):

## [Java (JDK 10)](http://jdk.java.net/), 21 bytes

```java
n->d->n.setScale(d,4)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##bVDRaoMwFH33Ky4FIRlp0G0va9c@jDHYw9hDH8WH1EQXp1HMtaMUv91Fq2s3BglJzjn3nHuTi4NY5vKz12VdNQi5e/NS4Ae/WXvXWIu6@BdLW5OgrsxAJoWwFt6ENnDyAOp2X@gELAp0x6HSEkrHkR022mRRDKLJLB2lAC@Tz@OTzp5VoktRsFeDM7yFFDa9WW7lcmu4VbhLRKGIZPe0X48G7/tcJRjFzheVRQubyRngBIuA34W381owCKFj1@yIBX/A4FfJw8x258C0aoDMqWPm6pxMf4IPogHjGjHqCy5zkekH6KCOgpiur@TSyYkbXGWqOQvCeOZ3R4uq5FWLvHYGmJKFnzLw5Qp86xvXo2EgGaRc1HVxJIZOF0mnjM4bdtd/Aw)

I would have loved to have submitted `n->n::setScale` (14 bytes) but alas, there is no default rounding, so we get `ArithmeticException` when rounding is required...

Answer (score 1):

## [MATL](https://github.com/lmendo/MATL), 13 bytes

```
i'%.'j'f'hhYD
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y00syfn/P1NdVU89Sz1NPSMj0uX/fxMuYwA)

#### Explanation:

```
i              % Grab first input: 0.32315
 '%.'j'f'      % Push the literal: ['%.' second input as string 'f'], where the input
               % specifies the number of decimals
         YD    % printf('%.sf',x)  where s is the second input, and x is the first
```

Comment: `hh` seems to be missing from the explanation. Also, I think you can remove `i` if you change the input order

Answer (score 1):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), <s>40</s> 36 bytes

```r
function(x,n)format(round(x,n),ns=n)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZqP7P600L7kkMz9Po0InTzMtvyg3sUSjKL80LwUsoJNXbJun@T9Nw0DP2NAIhhR0FAw1uUCChkCWAYRpgCJvqfkfAA)

(-4) thanks to [digEmAll](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/41725/digemall)

Comment: You can use partial matching for arguments, i.e. `nsmall=n` can be shortened to `ns=n`

Answer (score 1):

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 51 bytes

```julia
(x,d)->(y=string(round(x, d));y*"0"^(d-endof(y)+2))
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##Tc1BCsIwEIXhfU4xdDWjaZlUEKTUi4iCMEYiJSljC83pYxYKwlt9i/e/1incj0XHgpsVas@Yx/eiIT5R0xqlKgjRkHcNNzeU9hElecy074mKTwoeQoSLouvYgmOyoMjdwfW/Wfc1/jM40dXMtbNMET2ZemvKBw)

With trailing zeros as per the questions's "Trailing zeroes should be added with for example 0.1, 10" condition.

Julia's `@printf` can only take constant X values in `%.Xf` format strings (`%.4f`, etc.), so instead this code manually pads the required number of zeros if the rounded value has less than d digits after the decimal place.

First, store the rounded number as a string in `y`. Then, the number of digits after decimal point in `y` is `length(y) - 2` (`- 2` because the inputs are between 0 and 1, so there's one initial digit and then a decimal point to subtract). `endof(y)` is just a shorter way to write `length(y)` (at least for Julia v0.6).

Then, subtract this from the required number of digits `d`. Then, `(d-(endof(y)-2))` (= `(d-endof(y)+2)`) tells you how many digits are missing in the output (if any). Use that in `"0"^(d-endof(y)+2)` to get "0" repeated that many times, and then append that to `y` with the string `*` (concatenate) operator.

---

## [Julia 0.6](http://julialang.org/), 5 bytes

```julia
round
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##yyrNyUw0@19k@78ovzQv5X9afpFCmkJmnkJ0kYahnoGOgqGBpo5CkYaBnrGhEQzpGELFDJDEFCw1Y7kKijLzSnLyNNI0uVLzUrj@AwA)

Without trailing zeros, conforming to the summary "shortest way to round a float X with precision N on each language".

Comment: Could you use two `printf` like [this 43 bytes R solution?](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166428/80010)

Comment: Doesn't seem possible, unfortunately. The problem is that Julia's `@printf` parses its format string at compile time (for doing some type system magic), and as such requires the whole format string to be a compile-time constant. There are external packages to allow C-style or Python-style full-fledged format strings, but nothing builtin as of now.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification -  I get now what you meant by `constant` above. Too bad!

Answer (score 0):

74 Bytes Python 2.7

```
lambda x,y:str(x)[:y+2]if int(str(x)[y+2])<5else float(str(x)[:y+2])+.1**y
```

Messy but I think it works for all the scenarios.

Comment: Welcome to PPCG! :)

Comment: It fails if the `y` is greater than the precision of `x`: https://tio.run/##PYzBCsIwEETvfsVSCGTTUJqCl2K/RD1E2sVCbEOyQvP1MRHxNrx5Mz7xc9@GTNMtO/t6zBYOncbIQR54HVM73FeCdWP5Q5Xg5by4uAC53f6Lr4ttZ5RKebZsYSo7/2aJJx/KAzQkQoEiNiBAVkUDSVUDIuS@MxpM/wE

Answer (score 0):

## [Perl 6](https://perl6.org), 18 bytes

```perl6
{$^a.base(10,$^b)}
```

[Try it](https://tio.run/##bY5fS8MwFMXf8ykOo9rE1qxZZeDGpq8DcS@@qYP@SaXQrqVJRRn77DWp7TbBEJLDPef@7q1lU8y7Vkl8znmyJKT8xnVSpRKr7uDsIh5HSlIR@M4uZsfOuI9aKo3FCs7N5pknVRnTKd5SD68ud614f8CU8ayING8qXTU0ZPwpV9rA7ZwXaWVdRHt4PWtJsqoZsLdrUDj7toxl48NJ849cKyPkVy0TLVMwHAiQK9gdKbxT1hvCYBdxH5MhYPbJa56VmrpX4k65rC9QhnHI4FkLWK1xhkzIsQt4OBOzsL/wMSO2QMwrfIjA/sF4CNns61YvYCJjSyhMkyDbVo/OReoXcfb@RQV/UPcX8ZPzAw)

Answer (score 0):

## [05AB1E](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Commands), 10 [bytes](https://github.com/Adriandmen/05AB1E/wiki/Codepage)

```
.ò0¹²g-Ì∍J
```

`.ò` is the builtin that already gives the answer for most test cases. `0¹²g-Ì∍J` is to correctly append trailing zeroes if necessary.

[Try it online](https://tio.run/##MzBNTDJM/f9f7/Amg0M7D21K1z3c86ij1@v/f0MDLgM9QwA).

```python
.ò          # Round the second decimal input to the integer first input amount of decimals
            #  i.e. 10 and 0.1 → 0.1
            #  i.e. 1 and 0.67231 → 0.7
0           # Literal '0'
 ¹          # Get the first integer input
  ²g        # Get the length of the second decimal input
    -       # Subtract them from each other
     Ì      # Increase it by 2 for the "0." part
            #  i.e. 10 and 0.1 → 10-3+2 → 9
            #  i.e. 1 and 0.67231 → 1-7+2 → -8
      ∍     # Extend the "0" to a size of that length
            #  i.e. "0" and 9 → "000000000"
            #  i.e. "0" and -8 → ''
       J    # Join everything together
            #  i.e. 0.1 and "000000000" → 0.1000000000
            #  i.e. 0.7 and '' → 0.7
```

Answer (score 0):

## [Octave](https://www.gnu.org/software/octave/), 28 bytes

```matlab
@(x,y)printf(['%.',y,'f'],x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y08uSSxL/Z9mq6en999Bo0KnUrOgKDOvJE0jWl1VT12nUkc9TT1Wp0Lzf5qGiY66ibrmfwA)

Takes the first input as a number and the second as a string. Creates a formatting string: `%.yf` by concatenation, where `y` is the input that specifies the number of decimals. `x` is the input number that will be printed.

Answer (score 0):

## [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 42 bytes

```r
function(x,n)sprintf(paste0("%.",n,"f"),x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZqP7P600L7kkMz9Po0InT7O4oCgzryRNoyCxuCTVQENJVU9JJ09HKU1JU6dC83@ahoGesaERDCnoKBhqcoEEDYEsAwjTAEXeUvM/AA)

Failed attempt at outgolfing [DS_UNI](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/78898/ds-uni)'s [shorter R answer](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/a/166412/80010).

Even worse:

### [R](https://www.r-project.org/), 43 bytes

```r
function(x,n)sprintf(sprintf("%%.%if",n),x)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K/qfZqP7P600L7kkMz9Po0InT7O4oCgzryRNA0YrqarqqWamKQGldCo0/6dpGOgZGxrBkIKOgqEmF0jQEMgygDANUOQtNf8DAA)

Answer (score 0):

## [Kotlin](https://kotlinlang.org), 19 bytes

```
"%.${b}f".format(a)
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##y84vycnM@59WmqeQm5iZp5FYlF5speBYVJRYaRNcUpSZl26nqVDNxZmen5OmYaBnbGgEQzoKRppctVycXCC9YOlEKwWX/NKknFQdhSQrBc@8ErDOAqAhJTl5Gv@VVPVUqpNq05T00vKLchNLNBI1/3OCjPgPAA)

Comment: By default, submissions should be either a function or a full program. This is just a snippet that needs predefined variables `a` and `b`.

Answer (score 0):

## [Tcl](http://tcl.tk/), 31 bytes

```
proc R x\ n {format %.*f $n $x}
```

[Try it online!](https://tio.run/##K0nO@f@/oCg/WSFIoSJGIU@hOi2/KDexREFVTytNQSVPQaWi9n9ObmKBQmKMQpJCNZeBnrGhEQwpGAL5QNIASBkgCVty1SpUF5SWFCsoqSQqqCQpWClEBymAmbFKtf8B)